# zend framework get a variable from the controller to view

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework, class

I'm new to zend and OOP in general. I have a indexAction with a variable that I need to pass to the view. I've declared the variable as public and I thought I could then get the variable in the view using `$this->variable` but it doesn't work.

How do I pass a variable from indexAction to the view?

Comment: when using $this it should be within the class' methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Within indexAction, you need to assign it to the view instance. simply do:

```
$this->view->something = "foo";
```

and in your view:

```
<?php echo $this->something ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the assign method in the controller because it lets me nicely add multiple variables to the view

```
$this->view->assign('firstname', 'Peter')
           ->assign('lastname', 'Miller');
```

and in the view you can use the short open tag to `echo` things. And never forget to quote things.

```
<body>
  Firstname: <?= $this->escape($this->firstname); ?><br />
  Lastname: <?= $this->escape($this->lastname); ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->view->assign(array(
   'var1' => $value1,
   'var2' => $value2
));
```